# Path from ActivePerl in Windows 7 does not work

Tags: windows, perl, path

I have installed [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) on a Windows 7 machine. Everything is okay, but it cannot read a configuration file from the given path. The code I used is

```
use constant CONFIG_FNAME => '/windows/system32/softwareconfig.txt';
$self->{"config"} = &read_config_file($CONFIG_FNAME);
warn "read_config_file(CONFIG_FNAME) returned undef" if !defined($self->{"config"});
```

It always returns the warning. It works if I use the `softwareconfig.txt` in the same directory and `CONFIG_FNAME => 'softwareconfig.txt'`.

This code runs perfectly on Windows XP. I also tried following paths, but none seems to work. These all work perfectly in Windows XP.

```
CONFIG_FNAME => 'c:/windows/system32/softwareconfig.txt'
CONFIG_FNAME => 'c:\\windows\system32\softwareconfig.txt'
CONFIG_FNAME => 'c:\\windows\\system32\\softwareconfig.txt'
CONFIG_FNAME => "c:\\windows\\system32\\softwareconfig.txt"
CONFIG_FNAME => '\\windows\\system32\\softwareconfig.txt'
```

What can be done to correct this?

Comment: for sure is, that there is no need to use backslash on path. Just use forward slash. Perl substitutes this automatically. And no need to escape backslash in a single quoted string

Comment: escaped backslashes were inside the double quotes. I made typing error, and corrected in the original question.

Comment: @hexerei software, Perl does not do perform any substitution. Windows natively accepts both `\ ` and `/`  as path separators.

Comment: @Prabhu, `'c:\\windows\\system32\\softwareconfig.txt'` and `"c:\\windows\\system32\\softwareconfig.txt"` produce the same string.

Comment: @ikegami that is what i meant with "Just use forward slash. Perl substitutes this automatically." so `/windows/system32/test.txt` would have worked, if the rights where there

Comment: @hexerei software, That's the comment to which I was replying. It's wrong. Yes, it works, but no, Perl performs no substitution. Windows simply accepts both `\ ` and `/` as a path separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem likely has nothing to do with Perl. `Windows\system32` is a protected system directory, and Vista and later are rather protective of that location.

I do not recognize the file name `'softwareconfig.txt'` as being a standard Windows file. If you are putting your own configuration files in protected system directories, stop doing that.

[Environment::SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives you the list of special folders on Windows.

If the configuration file is for a specific user, then a subdirectory under `ApplicationData` is appropriate. If it is for all users, then a subdirectory under `CommonApplicationData` is appropriate.

Comment: I relocated the config file to `'d:\softwareconfig.txt'` now it is working. I think the problem was due to windows access restriction to system folder

Comment: you should place the file in your user directory, or in the application data directories as Sinan proposed

Answer (score 1):

Please, always `use strict;` and `use warnings` at the beginning of all your scripts. It says:

> Variable "$CONFIG_FNAME" is not imported at test1.pl line 7.
>       (Did you mean &CONFIG_FNAME instead?)

The two lines must be:

```
self->{"config"} = read_config_file(CONFIG_FNAME);
warn "read_config_file(".CONFIG_FNAME.") returned undef" if !defined($self->{"config"});
```

A constant is a bare word. A constant is not interpolated inside quotes.

Comment: I removed & before read_config_file() but the problem remains the same. Exact same code is working fine on XP machine with activeperl 8.10.

Comment: @Prabhu: Strange, it works fine for me. Did you remove the `$` before `CONFIG_FNAME`? May be `read_config_file` produces an error?

Comment: Yes, $ before CONFIG_FNAME was a typing mistake. I have already corrected it in my question

Answer (score 1):

Your Perl code seems okay. You can just use a single forward slash. Perl substitutes this automatically. So `/windows/system32/softwareconfig.txt` will work if the service or program that is trying to access the file has the permission to read from that path.

My recommendation: Try changing the permission of the configuration file to allow from everyone.